# Nested QML element onCompleted's signal not blocking the instanciation of QML objects

Tags: qt, signals, qml

Let's say I have a **main.qml** file:

```
import CustomWidgets 1.0

Item
{
    id: itemId
    anchors.fill: parent

    CustomWidget {}

    Component.onCompleted: // c++ function call
}
```

including a `CustomWidget` coming from another file called **CustomWidget.qml**:

```
Item
{
    id: customWidgetId
    anchors.fill: parent

    // attributes    

    Component.onCompleted: // c++ function call
}
```

Logically, the `CustomWidget onCompleted`'s signal is called before the main's one. But from what I've seen, it is not blocking, which means that the instanciation of the QML objects continues.

Is there a way to prevent that or another way around? My first `onCompleted` signal inits some data that is then accessed in the second signal.
Because of this current way of handling signals, my app is crashing while trying to access inexistant data (not yet initialized).

**EDIT:** I was thinking I could add a simple `bool` variable that would be set to `true` when the `CustomWidget onCompleted`'s signal is over. The other signal would wait with a loop.

Comment: Execution order of `onCompleted` handlers is undefined by design. I think you could have better luck in rethinking totally your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BaCaRoZzo already noticed you shouldn't build your app logic on assumption that items initialization will be in same order as visual one. Instead you can do something like that:

**CustomWidget.qml**

```
Item {
    signal initialized()

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // execute some code here
        initialized()
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Item {
    id: itemId

    CustomWidget {
        onInitialized: {
            // execute some secondary initialization
        }
    }
}
```